# How would this problem need the Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-writing

I'm asked to **square the inequality and use the Mean Value Theorem** to prove that

$$\sqrt{1+x} < 1 + \frac{x}{2}$$ for $x>0$.

Unfortunately, I don't really understand why I would need such a theorem here in the first place. Squaring the inequality, we get:

$$1+x < 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{4}$$

and thus:
$$0 < \frac{x^2}{4}$$

and therefore:
$$x^2 > 0$$

which obviously holds iff $x \neq 0$. Therefore, this especially holds for $x > 0$, q.e.d.

Sadly, the problem explicitly asks to use the Mean Value Theorem. Can anyone explain **why** I "need" and **how** I would apply the Mean Value Theorem here? What's the deal?

Comment: Can you give the exact problem statement?

Comment: *Show (by squaring and applying the Mean Value Theorem) that for $x > 0: \sqrt{1 + x} < 1 + \frac{x}{2}$.*

Comment: I would interpret it as asking to show the result twice (i.e., to two *different* proofs), once by squaring, and the second by applying the MVT.

Comment: I point out that you're wrong in saying that $x^2>0$ holds iff $x>0$. In fact, it holds for all real $x$ with the single exception of $0$. In addition, your chain of implications goes in exactly the wrong direction. You are assuming the result and "proving" the hypothesis.

Comment: @MPW You're right, thanks! Edited and hopefully corrected. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$ for $x > 0$. On the interval $(0,x)$:

$f(x) - f(0) = f'(c)(x - 0)$ for some $c \in (0,x)$. This gives:

$\sqrt{1+x} - 1 = \dfrac{x}{2\sqrt{1+c}} < \dfrac{x}{2}$ since $1 + c > 1$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! Could you leave a comment about the criteria that you have for choosing a good $f(x)?$ I might as well have chosen $f(x) := 1 + \frac{x}{2}$, couldn't I have? Is either side of the inequality going to lead me somewhere?

Comment: Observe that: $1 = (1+0)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  First write down carefully and accurately the Mean Value Theorem.  Then see if you can fill in missing steps and provide reasons for the following:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+0}}{x-0}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+c}}<\frac{1}{2}$$
where $0<c<x$.  If you can do this then the rest of the problem should be easy.